# How to filter a list in Prolog with multiple conditions?

Tags: filter, prolog

I can filter a list based on 1 condition with the following steps:

- building the list with `findall`
- using `include` to isolate the elements that respect the condition.

But how to proceed when there is multiple condition to respect? In this particular case, the number of condition and the conditions themselves are unknown, so the predicate has to be applicable to all contexts.

Here is an example of how the condition are build and how they are called:

```
goal(drinkingAge,(person(_,_,A))) :- person(_,_,A), A > 21. %has at least 21 years old
```

And to call them on a person:

```
goal(drinkingAge,(person("Tom",male,24))).
```

returns `true`

For now I can filter a list with 1 condition with the following:

```
findall(person(A,B,C),person(A,B,C),L).
include(goal(drinkingAge), L, ReturnList).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how "all contexts" are represented but, as [`include/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3) takes a *generic goal of 1 argument* as first argument (more precisely, the name of that goal), you can structure that goal accordingly.

For example, if you need to fulfill a series of 1-argument goals held in a list then:

```
succeed_all_goals_for_value([],_).
succeed_all_goals_for_value([Goal|Goals],Value) :-
   call(Goal,Value),                         
   succeed_all_goals_for_value(Goals,Value).
```

Then `include/3` can be called. For example, suppose `number/1`, `odd/1` and `notprime/1` are defined:

```
?- include(
       succeed_all_goals_for_value([number,odd,notprime]), 
       List,
       ListFiltered).
```

**With the more concrete `goal/2` syntax**

We can become more concrete now. Here is a possibility, complete with [plunit](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) test cases:

```
% ---
% Helper
% succeed_all_goals(+Goals,+Element). 
% ---

% Trivially succeed if there are no goals

succeed_all_goals([],_). 

% Otherwise go through the goals and succeed each one!
% There are many ways of doing this...

succeed_all_goals([GoalName|GoalNames],Element) :-
   goal(GoalName,Element),
   succeed_all_goals(GoalNames,Element).

% ---
% Call include/3 with a filtering goal
% that checks the conjunction of all conditions
% ---

myfilter(GoalNames,List,ListFiltered) :-   
   include(
      succeed_all_goals(GoalNames),
      List,
      ListFiltered).
      
% ---
% A bit of testing
% ---

% Succeed if second argument is a person who has reached drinking age
goal(drinkingAge, person(_,_,A)) :- A > 21.

% Succeed if second argument is a person who is male
goal(male, person(_,male,_)).

:- begin_tests(myfilter).

test(1) :- 
   myfilter(
      [drinkingAge,male],
      [person(jean,male,22),person(françoise,female,17)],
      ListFiltered),
   assertion(ListFiltered==[person(jean,male,22)]).
   
test(2) :- 
   myfilter(
      [male],
      [person(jean,male,22),person(françoise,female,17)],
      ListFiltered),
   assertion(ListFiltered==[person(jean,male,22)]).

:- end_tests(myfilter).
```

And so:

```
?- [greatfilter].
true.

?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: myfilter .. done
% All 2 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: The format of my goals is predetermined and isn't ```odd(x)```, but ```goals(odd,x)``` and I can't change this. Right now, the call inside ```succeed_all_goals_for_value``` always returns false, should I change something inside the function?

Comment: @JavaDumbell Can you add a concrete example to your question?

Comment: I just added a concrete example to the question, just let my know if you would like more information.

Comment: @JavaDumbell Ok, I see. That's a bit indirect, as `goal(drinkingAge,(person(_,_,A)))` basically puts the predicate name `drinkingAge` into the predicate name `goal`, it would be easier to just say `drinkingAge(person(_,_Age)) :- Age > 21.` (reminds me of that time in high school were a couple of companions were completely plastered at the back of class during the afternoon session on linear algebra, but I digress)

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use a **lambda expression** to estabilish the filtering condition. For instance:

```
?- include([X]>>(number(X), X mod 2 =:= 1), [1,a,2,[b,c],"def",3,4,g,5], R).
R = [1, 3, 5].

?- include([X]>>(number(X) ; atom(X)), [1,a,2,[b,c],"def",3,4,g,5], R).
R = [1, a, 2, 3, 4, g, 5].

?- include([X]>>not(number(X) ; atom(X)), [1,a,2,[b,c],"def",3,4,g,5], R).
R = [[b, c], "def"].
```