# Prolog: Filtering a list of goals and keeping the successful goals

Tags: prolog, restriction

Giving the following facts and restriction :

```
car(red, 2000).
car(black, 1990).
car(blue, 2010).

millennials(car(_,Y)) :- (car(_,Y)), Y =< 1995.
red(car(C,_)) :- car(C,_), C == red.
```

Given a list `[millennials, red]`, I would like to make a call such as:

```
checkRestriction([millennials, red], car(red, 2000) , L).
L = red
```

Which return a list of the conditions that are respected by the car passed as argument.

This is different from this thread: [How to filter a list in Prolog with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878954/how-to-filter-a-list-in-prolog-with-multiple-conditions/66879228?noredirect=1#comment118241575_66879228), because all restriction don't have to be successful, the goal is only to return a list of successful restriction with the car passed as argument.

I tried the following:

```
checkRestriction([],_,[]).
checkRestriction([H|T], Car, List) :-
   (    H(Car) 
   ->   append(L, H(Car), List), 
        checkRestriction(T, Car, List) 
   ;    checkRestriction(T, Car, List) ).
```

Which check is the restriction returns true with car as argument, and append in that case to a list the restriction itself, otherwise is simply call the predicate with the tail of the list, but I get compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal `H(Car)` causes a compilation error because a variable cannot be used as predicate name in Prolog. To correct your code, you must construct goal terms as follows:

```
?- H = red, Car = car(red,2000), Goal =.. [H,Car].
H = red,
Car = car(red, 2000),
Goal = red(car(red, 2000)).

?- H = millennials, Car = car(red,2000), Goal =.. [H,Car].
H = millennials,
Car = car(red, 2000),
Goal = millennials(car(red, 2000)).
```

Thus, the correct code is:

```
checkRestriction([], _, []).
checkRestriction([H|T], Car, Result) :-
    Goal =.. [H, Car],
    (   call(Goal)
    ->  Result = [H|List],
        checkRestriction(T, Car, List)
    ;   checkRestriction(T, Car, Result) ).

millennials(car(_,Y)) :- car(_,Y), Y =< 1995.

red(car(C,_)) :- car(C, _), C == red.
blue(car(C,_)) :- car(C, _), C == blue.
black(car(C,_)) :- car(C, _), C == black.
```

Running examples:

```
?- checkRestriction([millennials, red], car(red,2000), L).
L = [red].

?- checkRestriction([millennials, black], car(black,1990), L).
L = [millennials, black].

?- checkRestriction([millennials, blue], car(blue,2010), L).
L = [blue].

?- checkRestriction([millennials, black], car(blue,2010), L).
L = [].
```

Alternatively, you can use [`call/N`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2):

```
checkRestriction([], _, []).
checkRestriction([H|T], Car, Result) :-
    (   call(H, Car)
    ->  Result = [H|List],
        checkRestriction(T, Car, List)
    ;   checkRestriction(T, Car, Result) ).
```

Answer (score 0):

See the include/3 predicate in library(apply).
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src